# how to unit test components in vue.js that rely on external dependencies?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js

I am trying to write a unit test (with jest) that asserts that data is being pushed into job_execs.  The two issues I'm running into are mocking the api endpoint and if it's even possible to mock `this.$route.params.tool` in a unit test.

So the main question is, can I write a test with the component below? I know that it should be possible to mock the api endpoint (still haven't figured out how to), but my concern is that I have too many external dependencies in the component for this to be unit-testable.  Do I need to rewrite my component to support unit tests?

Jobs.vue

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Jobs",
  data() {
    return {
      job_execs: []
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.JobExecEndpoint = process.env.VUE_APP_UATU_URL + '/api/v1/job_execution/?tool='+this.$route.params.tool+'&job='+this.$route.params.job+'&id='+this.$route.params.id
    fetch(this.JobExecEndpoint)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
      this.job_execs.push({
        'code_checkouts': body[0].code_checkouts,
      })
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log('Error Fetching:', this.JobExecEndpoint, err);
      return { 'failure': this.JobExecEndpoint, 'reason': err };
    })
  },
};
</script>
```

unit test

```
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";
import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock'
import flushPromises from 'flush-promises'
import Jobs from "../../src/components/execution_details/Jobs.vue";

const job_execs = [
{
'code_checkouts': [{'name': 'test', 'git_hash': 'test', 'git_repo': 'test'}, {'name': 'test', 'git_hash': 'test', 'git_repo': 'test'}]}]
const $route = {
  params = {
  tool: 'jenkins',
  job: 'jobname',
  id: '1',
  }
}

describe('Jobs.vue', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetchMock.get(process.env.VUE_APP_UATU_URL + '/api/v2/job_execution/?product=eBay%20Mobile&tool='+$route.params.tool+'&job='+$route.params.job+'&id='+$route.params.id, job_execs)
  })

  it('Construct a JSON object of Git Refs from job_execution API', async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(GitRefs)
    await flushPromises()

    expect(wrapper.vm.job_execs).toEqual(job_execs)
  })

  afterEach(() => {
    fetchMock.restore()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import all the dependencies used in the component and also need to import whatever global values or properties used router, axios etc

Comment: when you say import them, do mean define them in the unittest ?